# Samba share setting permissions on Windows fails

Tags: permissions, samba, windows-10, acl, samba4

I have set up a samba4 ADC by the TecMint tutorial, [Create a Shared Directory on Samba AD DC and Map to Windows/Linux Clients – Part 7](https://www.tecmint.com/create-shared-directory-on-samba-ad-dc-and-map-to-windows-linux/), on Ubuntu 16.04.

It works well but when coming to configure the shared folder permissions on windows with the RSAT tools it fails. I've granted the SeDiskOperatorPrivilege privilege to the group of the AD user I'm logged in with in windows and set the owner of this share to this group (as in mentioned in the original Samba wiki, [Setting up a Share Using Windows ACLs](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_a_Share_Using_Windows_ACLs))

When setting the permissions in the security tab, Windows fails with:

In original german:

```
Fehler beim Anwenden der Sicherheit

Fehler beim Anwenden von Sicherheitsinformationen auf:

\\grisu\data\Demo

Fehler beim Aufzählen der Objekte im Container. Zugriff verweigert
```

Translated:

```
Error applying security

An error occurred while applying security information to:

\\grisu\Data\demo

Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied.
```

On Windows I've tried it with the user in the Unix Administrator (SeDiskOperatorPrivilege) group and the Samba Administrator - both with the same failure.

`smb.conf`: (note: samdom only for privacy)

```
# Global parameters
[global]
        workgroup = SAMDOM
        realm = SAMDOM.LAN
        netbios name = GRISU
        server role = active directory domain controller
        dns forwarder = 8.8.8.8
        idmap_ldb:use rfc2307 = yes

        template shell = /bin/bash
        winbind use default domain = true
        winbind offline logon = false
        winbind nss info = rfc2307
        winbind enum users = yes
        winbind enum groups = yes

[netlogon]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol/samdom.lan/scripts
        read only = No

[sysvol]
        path = /var/lib/samba/sysvol
        read only = No

[demo]
        path = /data/Demo
        read only = No
```

Shared folder:

```
root@grisu:~# getfacl /data/Demo
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: data/Demo
# owner: root
# group: SAMDOM\134unix\040admins
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::---
```

When trying the same sort of permission setting with the system created `netlogon` or `sysvol` share it works perfectly - so maybe some sort of permission problem on the Ubuntu side. When changing the permissions in the `sysvol` share, there is no popup about "inherited permissions in the tree".

On the hint from Rowland Penny I've tried to set up a new Samba AD DC on Ubuntu 20.04 and came to the conclusion, that the share is only a problem on the ZFS pool. Setting up a share on the "normal" disk from Ubuntu (ext4) works perfectly. I also tried to share directly out of the ZFS tool but there the Windows closes itself on entering the security tab.

Comment: Is this a question about Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: windows makes the failure popup, but I think it's a problem on the ubuntu side. I'm not sure...

Comment: Don't use Ubuntu 16.04, it's Samba version is too old, same goes for 18.04, so upgrade to 20.04 . The other thing: remove all the winbind lines, they do nothing on a Samba AD DC

Comment: I have tried it with 20.04 but then there was an failure on opening the security settings: when opened they loaded and closed themself immediately. After that failure a saw the tutorial was for 16.04 and tried with this version...

Comment: I set up a new samba AD DC with ubuntu 20.04 and came to the same problem again. On further investigation I came to the conclusion, it has something to do with the share i created on the ZFS filesystem.
Sharing a "normal" folder on the non-ZFS pool (the OS disk) works perfect...

Comment: Did you try to access `\\grisu\demo`?  (`demo` is actually the name that is known to Samba, not `/data/Demo`)

Comment: yes, that's how the share comes up in Windows

Comment: If I see correctoy, your system does not support ACL?