# glusterfs CTDB Samba - Windows permissions ACLs

Tags: networking, permissions, windows-10, acl, samba4

I have a testsetup consisting of two (three) nodes, 1 brick and a testshare.

The files are replicating and I see the files in every node. I set up CTDB and added the cluster to the Active Directory. With Windows 10 I can access the share only as administrator. I want to set the permissions for the users. As soon as I set the permissions with Windows an Error message appears stating "Failed to enumerate objects in the container. Access is denied.".

I set up different clusters within ubuntu, centos and debian. The latest setup is:

- Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- glusterfs 9.1
- CTDB: 4.9.5.Debian
- filesystem: ext4

Here is the current config for samba:

```
[global]
    clustering = Yes
    netbios name = CLUSTER3
    realm = MYDOMAIN.COM
    registry shares = Yes
    security = ADS
    template homedir = /home/%U
    winbind enum groups = Yes
    winbind enum users = Yes
    winbind use default domain = Yes
    workgroup = MYDOMAIN
    idmap config mydomain : backend = rid
    idmap config mydomain : range = 20000 - 29999
    idmap config * : range = 10000 - 19999
    idmap config * : backend = tdb
    map acl inherit = Yes
    vfs objects = acl_xattr

[media]
        comment = Media
        path = /mnt/glusterfs_vol_data/media
        read only = No
        acl_xattr:ignore system acl = yes
```

I also found a very similar problem here: [Samba share setting permissions on Windows fails](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314188/samba-share-setting-permissions-on-windows-fails)

Does anybody can give me a hint how to get the permissions working?
I also set up a fileserver with samba in the AD which works perfectly fine in terms of setting permissions with ubuntu 20.04 and Samba 4.11.6-Ubuntusamba. But setting up the cluster I run into problems with the file permissions.

Comment: Explore your permission/ownership problems with `https://github.com/waltinator/pathlld`. A `bash` script to answer "Why can't I Read/Write that file?".

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I could solve the problem. Mounting the gluster volume with ext4 file format one has to add the acl option resulting in:

```
mount -t glusterfs gfs1.MYDOMAIN.COM:/vol_data /mnt/glusterfs_vol_data -o acl
```

Hence, I can set the permissions.